# Is there common pairing of different English and German prepositions in the same sentences?

Tags: translation, word-usage, word-choice, preposition

German and English use different prepositions in the same sentence.
Some of these seem to me to be more often than others.
For example, "in" in the following German sentence and "on" in the English one:

> Er hat ein Foto **in** dem sozialen Netzwerk geteilt.
>
> He shared a photo **on** the social network.

Is the above switching common and, if so, are there others that could be similarly paired?

Comment: It's totally unclear what you're asking about. Do you mean translation of English _on_ to German _auf_ vs. _in_ Can you clarify your question please.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. Pronouns have to be learned for the word you want to use. It might be the same as in English, it might be different. There's no "one size fits all" rule.

Comment: Actually, German adds another level of complication, as there are nine prepositions which mean a different thing when used with accusative or dative, and another set of prepositions which take a different case when used as postpositions. Plus, often prepositions morph into separable verb prefixes and then *also* mean a different thing. And of course, those who became inseparable verb prefixes mean just another different thing.

Comment: @Janka That is hardly a German quirk. Sure, German *in/in* corresponds to *in/into*, but *unter/unter* doesnt map to *under/underto*, but simply to *under/under*. So it's not as if  speakers of English are unfamiliar with inferring the precise meaning from context.

Comment: But the question targets exactly that: *Are there pairs of prepositions matching each other.* The answer is, **there are more exceptions than rules**.

Answer (score 3):

That German "in" translates to "on" in English is not very common.

German "in" often translates to English (surprise, surprise) "in": "Im [=in dem] Haus" / "In the House", "In Deutschland" / "In Germany"

English "on" often translates to "auf": "On the roof" / "Auf dem Dach", "On page 6" / "Auf Seite 6"

But these are only rules of thumb. The correct use of prepositions is complicated, and the exact rules differ between English and German.